# How to get score to get updated and display on screen?

Tags: python, pygame

When player touches coin score gets updated and displayed the score gets overlapped e.g. 1,2,3 etc making unclear to see the score. I am trying to get it so the previous score disappears and only the new one is shown.

```
def main():  #my main loop 
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
    score = (1)
    score = str(score)

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('OpenSans', 30)        
textsurface = myfont.render('Level ONE:   Greenland', False, (0, 0, 0))        
background.blit(textsurface,(500,10))

textsurface = myfont.render('Score:', False, (0, 0, 0))        
background.blit(textsurface,(10,10))

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, coin_list,True) 
        for coin in player_hit_list:
             textsurface = myfont.render(score, False, (0, 0, 0))
             background.blit(textsurface,(90,10))
             score = str(int(score)+ 1))

    sprites.update()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    sprites.draw(screen)  # Draws all of the sprites onto the screen
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
    pygame.display.update()
```

I except on the top left it shows Score: 1 and when the coin is touched it get updated e.g. Score:

Comment: Each time you get a new score, you need to either *update* the old object, or delete it when you create the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PyGame surface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) `subsurface()` [function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface), copy the part of the background that is directly under the core, probably adding a bit extra to handle more digits in the core.

Then to update the score, erase the existing score by writing that section of the background, then paint the text bitmap.

Something like:

```
# rectangle around score
under_score_rect = [ 90, 10,  100,  40 ]  
# copy of background that's under the score
under_score_background = background.subsurface( under_score_rect ).copy()

...

def drawScore( score, screen, background_img ):
    global score_font
    textsurface = score_font.render( score, False, (0, 0, 0) )
    screen.blit( background_img, ( 90, 10 ) )
    screen.blit( textsurface, ( 90,10 ) )

...

drawScore( score, window, under_score_background )
```